# Python - How to Filter a Dataframe with Groupby and row index?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

| Name | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| John | a,b,c,d,e |
| John | a,b,c,d |
| John | a,b,d |
| Jane | a,b,d |
| Jane | a,b,e |
| Jane | a,c,e |

I am trying to filter it so that if, let's say d or b, appear in the last sequence row grouped by name, all of those name rows and sequence rows remain in the dataframe. Otherwise, they are dropped. So in this example, all of John's rows would remain, because his last sequence is [a,b,d] which contains b or d, but all of Jane's information would be dropped because b or d does not appear in her last row ([a,c,e]).

| Name | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| John | a,b,c,d,e |
| John | a,b,c,d |
| John | a,b,d |

I am not sure how I could code this because I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated the dataframe using -

```
data = [
    ('John', ['a','b','c','d','e']),
    ('John', ['a','b','c','d']),
    ('John', ['a','b','d']),
    ('Jane', ['a','b','d']),
    ('Jane', ['a','b','e']),
    ('Jane', ['a','c','e'])
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Sequence'])
```

The output of which is -

```
Name    Sequence
0   John    [a, b, c, d, e]
1   John    [a, b, c, d]
2   John    [a, b, d]
3   Jane    [a, b, d]
4   Jane    [a, b, e]
5   Jane    [a, c, e]
```

Now, I have defined a function that checks if some particular elements are present inside a list or not, or in your case if both "b" and "d" are present inside the Sequence column or not.

```
def check_if_char_present(col: list, li_char: list) -> bool:
    return False in [True if char in col else False for char in li_char]
```

We need to find the names that do not have the specified characters, hence we return a true only if None or even one of the elements to be checked is/are not present.Then I will retrieve the required names -

```
names = df.groupby(["Name"], as_index=False).last().apply(lambda x: x["Name"] if check_if_char_present(x["Sequence"], ["b", "d"]) else None, axis=1)

names = [name for name in names if name is not None]
```

Firstly, the dataframe is grouped according to the "Name" column. To prevent the column on which the dataframe is grouped to become the index, we use `as_index = False`. Then, we retrieve the last rows of each group using last(). For each last row in the groups, we check for our elements in the *Sequence* column using `apply()` and create a list of *None*;for each name having the required characters and names; if the elements are not present in their respective *Sequence* column.

Then, the **None** elements in the list are removed to leave only the required names which gives -

```
>>> ['Jane']
```

as the output. Finally, we remove the rows which have the names present inside the list using -

```
df = [temp_df:= df.drop(df.loc[df["Name"] == name].index) for name in names][0]

print(df)
>>> Name    Sequence
0   John    [a, b, c, d, e]
1   John    [a, b, c, d]
2   John    [a, b, d]
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but it unfortunately did not work for some reason.

Comment: Did you face any error ? Or wrong output ?

Comment: No error but the wrong output. The second step is returning this list : names = ['name', 'sequence']

Comment: The first function if I run it by itself also returns True even if I pass a list of nonsense to it that I know is not presented in the column

Comment: That's weird, it still works fine on my side. Can you please post a sample of your dataframe using [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) ?